# IIS6 redirect to tomcat %2B

Tags: tomcat, iis-6, windows-server-2008

We are using an IIS6 and worker to have acces to the tomcat. 
This worked well for years.

Now we have an problem with the url en/decoding between IIS and the tomcat.

Some Data have an String-ID like `F+B` so we are calling the show Site like this `foo.bar/showF%2BB` and this worked until yesterday.

The Problem here is that the tomcat needs this URL to find the object, but the URL that comes to the tomcat look like this `foo.bar/show/F+B` and with that it doesn't find the object.

We didn't changed something on the server for years...

Why and what does `F%2BB` convert to `F+B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found a solution =)

We are using the jakarta Isapi to redirect from the IIS to the tomcat and we added a single line to the config and it works:

```
  uri_select = unparsed
```

With that everything is directly parsed to the tomcat, the IIS doesn't do more (such as other filter f.e. SQLInjectionFilter).